# how to obtain accurate depth map?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    long lframecount=0;
    //load the videos
    VideoCapture capture1(argv[1]); 
    VideoCapture capture2(argv[2]);
    cout << argv[1]  << endl;
    cout << argv[2]  << endl;

    if(!capture1.isOpened()||!capture2.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"cant load stereo video";
        return -1;
    }

    Mat frame1,frame2;
    capture1>> frame1;
    capture2>> frame2;
    long framecount1= capture1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    long framecount2= capture2.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);



    namedWindow("depthmap",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);


    cv::Mat disp;
    cv::Mat vdisp;
    for(long i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        lframecount++;
        int number=lframecount;
        string frame;
        std::ostringstream convert;
        convert<<number;
        frame = convert.str();
        //cout<<lframecount<<"\n";
        capture1 >> frame1;
        capture2 >> frame2;
        cv::StereoVar stereo;

        stereo.minDisp=-80;
        stereo.maxDisp=80;
        stereo(frame1,frame2,disp);
        double min, max;
        minMaxLoc(disp, &min, &max);
        disp.convertTo(vdisp, CV_8U, -255.0/max, 255);

        std::cout<<"framecount :"<< frame<<std::endl;
        imshow("depthmap",vdisp);
        waitKey(30);
        write << vdisp;
        //waitKey(30);
        //if(waitKey(0))
        //break;
    }
    write.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

here is my code.I am getting lot of noise in the image.I am using the image taken from my camera.can anyone suggest me a good method?or can  anyone point out the error?am using stereo var function avaliable in the opencv..is ther anyother function which will give better results?

Comment: Please post your image.

Comment: i am unable to post my image..how to do???

Comment: Put it in other server and post there a link to it

Comment: See this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60563/how-to-upload-images-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the function [`cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20cvFindStereoCorrespondenceBM%28const%20CvArr%2a%20left,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20right,%20CvArr%2a%20disparity,%20CvStereoBMState%2a%20state%29)

But first: **Have you calibrated your camera?**

Maybe you should check [this](http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/01/opencv-stereo-camera-calibration.html) tutorial on how to calibrate your camera using OpenCv and [this](http://blog.martinperis.com/2011/08/opencv-stereo-matching.html) about on to compute the depth map (also called *disparity map*).

Comment: without calibration also we can get image rectification right??i used surf features to get the fundamental matrix and in turn i found out the rectified image..now i am trying to obtain the disparity map.i used cv::findStereoCorrespondanceBM but i was not able to get proper result.there are lot of noise in the image.is there any consideration while taking the image?//

Comment: Are you using stereovision to rectify one image? If so, maybe you should consider to modify your question and include the exact question.